# jQuery datatables hidden column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I create datatables with jQuery

In have following list :

```
var list = [["name1", "id1"],["name2", "id2"],["name3", "id3"]]
```

I initialize datatables :

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate" : false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSortClasses": false
})
```

and

add datas :

```
oTable.fnAddData(list);
```

it shows name1, name2, name3

My question: can I add id1, id2, id3 as hidden datas?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [ 
            /* name1 */   null,                                     /*  visible */
            /* id1 */  { "bVisible":    false },                    /* hidden */
            /* name2 */  null,
            /* id2 */  { "bVisible":    false },
            /* name3 */    null,
            /* id3 */  { "bVisible":    false }
        ]
    });
});
```